# Windows ping timeout parameter doesn't seem to work

Tags: windows, timeout, ping

If I do 'ping -w 5 google.com' from a command prompt on my Windows XP (also Windows 7) box, I get all packets returned successfully, but all have a trip time of more than 5 ms.  Am I mis-understanding how the -w flag is supposed to work?

Thanks,
Al.

Comment: Works find on my Windows 7 machine, I lose all 4 packets.

Comment: That's odd, no machine I have tried it on works - XP Pro, Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: I got the same result as you using Windows 7 Home Premium.  I also tried it with a very long delay and a non-existent IP address, but ping doesn't wait.  The timeout seems to make no difference in either case.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 8 too...

Comment: I don't currently have a Windows machine to test it on , but from memory this timeout applies only when no packets are received back, otherwise it will wait for two RTTs

Comment: Also having that issue on Windows 7 Ultimate: ping with 10 ms but it takes between 150 - 500 ms (!) .....

Answer (score -1):

The [following documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcc2xffs(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> When specifying very small numbers for timeout, the Ping reply can be
>   received even if timeout milliseconds have elapsed.

After some testing, this seems to explain your issue. I have tested pinging example.com, wich replies between 70-85ms for me. When setting timeout to 80ms, some pings fail, and some don't. So, somewhere below 80ms starts to be "very small".